# Jquery and CSS not working after XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code on test.php displays all contents from testfile2.php every 3 seconds. This works fine but all jquery & css links are not being seen whether they are in test.php or testfile2.php

```
function refresh()
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("Grabbing Value");
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById('monitor').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", 'testfile2.php', true);
    req.send(null);
}

function init()
{
    refresh()
    var int = self.setInterval(function ()
    {
        refresh()
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors logged in console?

Comment: So your response text is an HTML document and you're attempting to load it in every three seconds?

Comment: Devan - no errors in console

Comment: zfrish - testfile2.php is parsing a json return and that is what is being displayed.

Comment: by "jquery ... not being seen" do you mean that jquery is never loaded? What is the output if you execute `$` in console.

Comment: " jquery & css links" <-- what are jquery and css links? Unclear

Comment: jquery is all in testfile2.php and the return in console is ƒ (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} . If I put the jquery in test.php, it works fine but it does me no good because I need to put the return from testfile2.php in tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code, it seems like testfile2.php will give back html code which you will use to insert into your current page with innerHTML. However doing so will not execute the javascript, you have to use [eval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to execute any javascript returned

Check out the answer of similar question also
[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)